# How display the output of calculation in decimal point using bc command

Tags: bash, bc

I want to do simple coding by storing the output calculation in variable and display the result in decimal point using command `bc`. But it only works on for minus calculation not for division calculation.

```
numberTotalX=$(echo "$varnameY - $var1" | bc)

echo " Number.total.x is $numberTotalX "
```

the result is:

```
Number.total.x is 7443.576
```

but when it come to this command:

```
numberSplitInteger=$(echo "$numberTotalX / $var2" | bc)

echo " Number of split integer is $numberSplitInteger "
```

the result is normal integer not in decimal point

```
Number of split integer is 2461
```

Comment: What does `numberTotalX` and `var2` contain in your example?

Comment: Look up `scale` in `man bc`

Comment: I set var2=3.024 and varnameY=7485.912 in the coding.

Comment: scale defines how some operations use digits after the decimal point. The default value of scale is 0. (bc command man page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `scale`, just use:

```
 numberSplitInteger=$(echo "scale=x;$numberTotalX / $var2" | bc)
```

It will give you `x` values after decimal.

Comment: Thanks! now it able to display the decimal point